# Multiple munin-node daemons with different plugins on same machine

Tags: monitoring, munin

my company recently moved to a new infrastructure provider. We got a partially managed server there with a basic installation of Ubuntu 14.04. The provider also has munin-node (munin version 2.0.19) installed on the machine with some custom plugins for *their* monitoring.

Now, we would like to use *our own* monitoring which we had in place before changing providers, also. We have a munin-master up and running. Our monitoring includes a few more plugins which we developed ourselves to monitor our applications. So, while I don't want their plugins, they don't need ours. Some of our plugins also employ reset-on-read counters.
This means simply allowing our munin-master on the munin-node and additionally read the stats from there is no solution.

What I actually need is a second munin-node daemon running on the machine. I could do this by simply copying the init.d startup scripts, changing ports etc, creating another plugins dir and put our additional plugins there.

However, I can't find a way to *change the plugin dir* munin uses. I can set another config file to read, but there seems to be no option to specify plugin location. There is also no command line option for munin-node (though, other scripts like munin-run and munin-node-configure seem to have them). I tried googling, I've been in the source code, but I can't find any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I came up with, which might not be the best solution, but it works:

- copy `/etc/munin` to `/etc/munin2`
- modify settings in `munin-node.conf`

  - log_file: change to `.../munin-node2.log`
  - pid_file: change to `.../munin-node2.pid`
  - port: change to `4948` (or whatever suits you best)
- add/remove plugins in `plugins/` as needed
- modify settings in `plugin-conf.d/` and `munin-node.conf` as needed
- copy `/usr/sbin/munin-node` to `/usr/sbin/munin-node2`
- in `munin-node2`, insert `$Munin::Common::Defaults::MUNIN_CONFDIR='/etc/munin2';` after  the last `use ...;`
- copy `/etc/init/munin-node.conf` to `/etc/init/munin-node2.conf`
- in `munin-node2.conf`, modify

  - `[ -r /etc/default/munin-node ] && . /etc/default/munin-node` to `[ -r /etc/default/munin-node2 ] && . /etc/default/munin-node2`
  - `exec /usr/sbin/munin-node $DAEMON_ARGS` to `exec /usr/sbin/munin-node2 $DAEMON_ARGS`

Now, you should be able to start the second munin node by `service munin-node2 start`, and `ps ax|grep munin-node` should show it running alongside the primary one.

All that is now needed is to mention the other port for that particular munin-node inside your `munin.conf` or `munin-conf.d/` on your munin-master.